# Running MPI code with 256 procs - "[warn] select: Invalid argument" message

Tags: macos, mpi, limit, macos-high-sierra, ulimit

Following the tutorial on [this link](https://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.2.3/using/performance/open-files-limit/#mac-os-x-older-versions), I try to run a MPI code under MacOS 10.9.5 (Mavericks) with a number of process equal to 256 : the MPI code allocates for each process a `512x512` 2D array, so it requires 256*256kB = 64MB of total used memory.

My MacOS has 16GB RAM and 8 cores, so it seems to be weird.

For a number of process lower than 256 (I tried : np=2,4,8,16,32,64,128), there is no problem, execution is good and I get expected results.

But for `np = 256`, I get the following message which repeats itself:

```
$ mpirun -np 256 ./a.out

    [warn] select: Invalid argument
    [warn] select: Invalid argument
    [warn] select: Invalid argument
     ...
```

I tried also to use `-mca` option by doing:

```
$ mpirun -mca opal_set_max_sys_limits 1 -np 256 ./a.out
```

But I get the same warning message.

From this [link](https://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.2.3/using/performance/open-files-limit/#mac-os-x-older-versions) cited above, I did:

```
$ launchctl limit maxfiles
  
  maxfiles    65536          200000
```

Then, in root user, I created `/etc/launchd.conf` file and put into:

```
limit maxfiles 65536 200000
```

I restarted the system for the new limits to take effect and type as normal user:

```
$ launchctl limit maxfiles

maxfiles    65536          200000
```

But unfortunately, these modifications have no effects on the MPI function "mpirun" with 256 processes and don't make disappear the warning above.

On Linux platform, I can launch my MPI code with `np = 256`, without problem, the issue is only happening on MacOS 10.9.5.

### Update 1

I have also tried to use "`--oversubscribe`" option like:

```
mpirun -np 256 --oversubscribe ./a.out
```

but get still the same message : `[warn] select: Invalid argument`

### Update 2

I have upgraded to OS X 10.13.3 High Sierra but still have no luck with my issue.

To increase the limit of open files, from this [link](https://www.macobserver.com/tips/deep-dive/evade-macos-many-open-files-error-pushing-limits/) I did:

1. `sudo vim /Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist`
2. put into this file:

   Label
     limit.maxfiles
     ProgramArguments
     
     launchctl
     limit
     maxfiles
     64000
     524288
     
     RunAtLoad
     
     ServiceIPC
3. `sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist`
4. Checking by:

   $ sysctl kern.maxfiles

   kern.maxfiles: 524288

and:

```
$ launchctl limit maxfiles

maxfiles    64000          524288
```

When I launch ring_c.c (example from Open-MPI) executable with:

```
mpirun --oversubscribe -np $NB_PROCESS ./a.out
```

For a number of processes lower or equal to `142`, it's running fine.

For a number of processes greater than `142`, I get the original warning message:

```
[warn] select: Invalid argument
[warn] select: Invalid argument
[warn] select: Invalid argument
[warn] select: Invalid argument
[warn] select: Invalid argument
[warn] select: Invalid argument
[warn] select: Invalid argument
...
```

Why the limit is reached at `NB_PROCESS > 142`? what does it correspond to? I didn't see this limit anywhere.

Comment: Please show a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable version of your code.

Comment: Try `ulimit -S -n 49000` and `ulimit -S -u 2048` before running.

Comment: -@Mark Setchell : I tried your commands but issue remains for a number of processes > `142` (NB_PROCESS) with : `mpirun --oversubscribe -np $NB_PROCESS ./a.out`. You can test the MPI code donwloadable on : http://31.207.34.24/test_mpi/ring_c.c

Comment: Works fine with open-mpi  3.0.0 on High Sierra including 512 processes. `brew install open-mpi` and `ulimit` per my previous comment.

Comment: If you have upgraded macOS, I would suggest you uninstall `open-mpi`, update `Xcode` if necessary, re-run `xcode-select --install`, re-install `open-mpi` and re-compile.

Comment: I am using `macport` but I think this should work like with `brew`. Which compiler have you used for your `open-mpi` installation ?

Comment: I used `gcc 7.2`

Comment: I built `open-mpi 3.0.0` with `gcc-mp-7` (7.3) and set :`ulimit -a`
`core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 49000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 2048
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited`
**unfortunately,still message**

Comment: Finally fixed by using external libevent for open-mpi-3.0 (built from libevent-2.1.8 version) and the following configure : `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/openmpi CC=gcc-mp-7 CXX=g++-mp-7 FC=gfortran-mp-7 --with-libevent=external --with-libevent=/usr/local/libevent/`